# Creating A Linux at Job (scheduling) in Python

Tags: python, linux, cron

I'm trying to schedule a number of jobs in linux using a python script. Currently, my script looks something like this:

```
import subprocess
command = 'python foo.py %s %s | at %s' % (arg1, arg2, starttime) 
subprocess.Popen([command,], shell=True)
```

But this doesn't appear to work and I was hoping someone might be able to advise on what I should be doing.

Comment: Popen can run a single command, but what you have is an entire pipeline. If foo.py is in python, why don't you just import it, though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what is your problem is the use of the `at` command, it shall get a string, so what you want is more

```
command = 'echo python foo.py %s %s | at %s' % (arg1, arg2, starttime)
```

or in a more pythonic way

```
sched_cmd = ['at', starttime]
command = 'python foo.py %s %s' % (arg1, arg2)
p = subprocess.Popen(sched_cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate(command)
```

Comment: I always tend to avoid using shell=True, as you can't manage your inputs and the behaviour correctly.

Answer (score 3):

If you pass in `shell=True`, `Popen()` expects a string:

```
import subprocess
command = 'python foo.py %s %s | at %s' % (arg1, arg2, starttime) 
subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
```

Also, what do you mean by "isn't working"? It works fine for me:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.Popen('echo "asd" | rev', shell=True).communicate()
dsa
(None, None)
```

And your code as well:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.Popen(['echo "asd" | rev',], shell=True).communicate()
dsa
(None, None)
```